# dojo or jquery javascript send binary file using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, file-upload, dojo

I want to upload a static file on my drive like C:\someplace\somefile.doc
THe file and location is always the same.

I need to do an ajax POST to a url to send this file using only javascript...

Could someone provide some idea or example how this could be done using dojo or jquery...is this possible?

I seen examples where it uses a form...but that is not I want.

thanks

Comment: you may be able to do this with javascript+flash. uploadify is a possibility: [http://www.uploadify.com/about/](http://www.uploadify.com/about/)

Comment: Well, most modern browsers are designed to prevent JavaScript programs from accessing your local hard drive -- for very good security reasons.  The only way is through the file-upload mechanism in a form.  You should RETHINK whether you need this in the first place.  If a JavaScript program can get a file from your hard disk, which means that somebody else can write a web page to get stuff from your computer without you knowing, or worse, wipe your hard drive clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant upload files from your local computer using javascript without using the built in upload function (the form).

Comment: they designed it this way for security reasons. or else malicious scripts could upload your harddrive without the user knowing.

Comment: form needs to be `enctype="multi-part/form-data"` fwiw

Answer (score 0):

MDN has an article on how to do it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_files_from_web_applications

Check 'Handling the upload process for a file'.

They don't use jQuery but the new HTML5 File AP and XmlHttpRequest 2.